# How to make a Flash or HTML5 Panorama

Tags: software-recommendation, panorama

Is there any open source tool for Ubuntu that could make a flash/HTML5 panoramic? I have made a few panoramas using Hugin, and I would love to be able navigate them from a browser. Pano2vr works nicely, however if there is an open source alternative I would love to use it.

Thank you for your time and answers.

Comment: [This](http://www.mullrail.co.uk/panorama.htm) uses Java, but I do not know how to implement it. There is also [this](http://www.labnol.org/internet/embed-panorama-images/), but none of these seem to implement 360° panoramas.

Comment: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12765/online-viewer-for-panorama-photos as well -  uses Flash. This  suggest pan0, which looks very good.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy responses, I will check these out after work. Ubuntu has such a great community :)

Comment: Wilf if you put pan0 as an answer I would like to choose that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Pan0](http://pan0.net/) is a very good looking panorama viewer

It is free, fast, and makes the panoramas look impressive. It uses a Flash-based spherical panorama viewer, which you can even embed into your own site or blog. Unlike Gigapan, Panoramio and similar sites, pan0.net takes care of perspective transforms, and allows to view the panorama as if you were rotating your head - it is not just zooming and panning a large flat image. It is much more immersive.

**It Features**

- very immersive spherical panorama player (open source)
- support for 360°×180° and partial panoramas (if angle of view is set)
- interactive map reference (also the view direction on the map)
- hotspots on the panorama (text or image)
- virtual tours
- panoramas are embeddable (just like you embed youtube videos)
- small and large resolution views, view on black or view on white

**Upload limits**

- Source panorama image can go up to 8000×4000, but it is effectively ‘rescaled to 5000×2500 for smooth panorama preview’;

[image: pan0]

---

Credit to @sastanin, from whom I sourced this info off StackExchange's Photography Site:
https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12765/online-viewer-for-panorama-photos

Answer (score 1):

The only one I've ever considered for web use is [krpano](http://krpano.com). While it does have Linux tools, it's pretty expensive. But that's less of a problem when you have a client footing the bill.

There are others out there. [Pannellum](https://github.com/mpetroff/pannellum) might be a suitable free replacement. I don't think the quality (and client side performance) is as good though (there's no scaling in it yet so you're loading the whole picture at once *shudder*). It just takes [a rectangle matched-edge panorama](https://github.com/mpetroff/pannellum/blob/master/examples/examplepano.jpg) (like Hugin can output).

There's also [Pano2VR](http://ggnome.com/pano2vr) which looks quite interesting. It seems to build a shape in the browser (more facets than a cube but a lot less than a sphere) and textures that with individual images and that results in fairly decent performance. Not free though. And *really* not free if you want to take their branding off it.

Answer (score 0):

I was using http://www.dermandar.com/. It's not as good as Hugin cause it creating panorama automaticly, but it gives code for you site.